# Mysql error creating table after connecting to Amazon RDS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysqli, amazon-rds

I can connect to the RDS ok but when I try the following script to create table I get an error.

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'rdsdari.MYRDSNAME.rds.amazonaws.com');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'Rds1');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Rds1');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'Rds1');

  /* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  $database = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);

  /* Ensure that the Employees table exists. */
  VerifyEmployeesTable($connection, DB_DATABASE);

  /* If input fields are populated, add a row to the Employees table. */
  $employee_name = htmlentities($_POST['Name']);
  $employee_address = htmlentities($_POST['Address']);

  if (strlen($employee_name) || strlen($employee_address)) {
    AddEmployee($connection, $employee_name, $employee_address);
  }
?>

<!-- Input form -->
<form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="POST">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Address</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="45" size="30" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Address" maxlength="90" size="60" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Data" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<!-- Display table data. -->
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>

<?php

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Employees");

                                                                                                                   6,34          Top
}
?>

</table>

<!-- Clean up. -->
<?php

  mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($connection);

?>

</body>
</html>


<?php

/* Add an employee to the table. */
function AddEmployee($connection, $name, $address) {
   $n = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
   $a = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $address);

   $query = "INSERT INTO `Employees` (`Name`, `Address`) VALUES ('$n', '$a');";

   if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo("<p>Error adding employee data.</p>");
}

/* Check whether the table exists and, if not, create it. */
function VerifyEmployeesTable($connection, $dbName) {
  if(!TableExists("Employees", $connection, $dbName))
  {
     $query = "CREATE TABLE `Employees` (
         `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
         `Address` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
         UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

     if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo("<p>Error creating table.</p>");
  }
}

/* Check for the existence of a table. */
function TableExists($tableName, $connection, $dbName) {
  $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $tableName);
  $d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $dbName);

  $checktable = mysqli_query($connection,
      "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$t' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$d'");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($checktable) > 0) return true;

  return false;
}
?>
```

and now I get

Error creating a table.

Error adding employee data.

Comment: can you create table via CLI ?

Comment: Login as admin and check again whether you assign/grant the proper roles/services to the user,  afterwards, flush the priviledges

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 0):

First you might wanna copy the starter code on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

which is same as your code.

If you still get an error you can replace both these statements `echo("<p>Error creating table.</p>")` and `echo("<p>Error adding employee data.</p>")` with `echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connection));` to get detailed error code message